# why this code doesn't work (string function)?

Tags: python, string

I have a piece of python code

```
def getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed):
    str='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    for i in lettersGuessed:
        if i in str:
            str.replace(i,'')
    return str
getAvailableLetters(['a','v','k','k','l','i','o','0'])
```

The problem is that `str.replace(i,'')` doesn't work. Please help me in understand why?

Comment: i don't know how to edit in stack exchange , someone please help me in edit , please share some documentation about how to edit this

Comment: @andrej kesely Thanks!

Comment: Press the 'edit' button under the words 'python' and 'string' This will take you to the edit screen.

Comment: do i need to delete this question?? since it is a duplicate

Comment: Sidenote: With the current logic you have, you don't need `if i in str:` line, because `str.replace` won't error if `i` is not present in `str`.

Comment: @CloudJR no, it serves as a signpost to the duplicate question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str.replace(i,'')` doesn't not change the actual string, you would need

```
str = str.replace(i,'')
```

Comment: Note that `str` is a terrible name for a variable, since `str` is the built-in name for the string type.

Comment: @AdamSmith True.

Comment: See the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), particularly the bullet point regarding questions which "*have already been asked and answered many times before*".

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you for the link. Honestly it is the first time I see the linked duplicate and I just went and upvoted it. I won't answer that type of question in the future.